# Custom implementation of `Object.create` not involving private `function`

Tags: javascript

According to various sources, including the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), if one was to create a custom implementation of the simpler version of `Object.create` then it would go like this:

```
if (typeof Object.mycreate1 !== 'function') {
    Object.mycreate1 = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

However, as `new` basically creates a new instance and calls `F` on it, I wonder whether or not this is also correct:

```
if (typeof Object.mycreate2 !== 'function') {
   Object.mycreate2 = function( o ) {
      var _ = { };
      _.prototype = o;
      return _;
   }
}
```

Simple tests suggest that this works:

```
var p = { name : 'Jan', surname : 'Kowalski' };
var q = Object.mycreate2( p );

q.surname = 'Malinowski';
p.surname = 'Kowalski';

console.log( q.surname );
console.log( p.surname );
```

The question is: is the latter implementation correct? If no, I'd also like to know why.

I *might* probably know the answer: object's `prototype` property is read only and while it works in FireFox, it shouldn't. On the other hand, function's `prototype` is read-write and it can be changed.

The problem with this hypothetical answer is that I can't validate it in the specs.

Comment: I don't think your test is valid.

Comment: `console.log(q.name); // undefined`. If `p` is in `q`'s prototype chain, it should log `"Jan"`.

Comment: Most objects don't have a `.prototype` property. (They only do if you give it one, and then it's just a normal property.) Only function objects have one by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function is not equivalent to the first. Setting the "prototype" property of a simple object doesn't have any effect.  A better test:

```
 var x = Object.mycreate2({foo: "bar"});
 console.log(x.foo); // undefined
```

The "prototype" property of a **constructor** function is interesting, because it actually does have a role in establishing the inheritance chain for a constructed object.

Comment: Does it mean that a custom `Object.create` **has to** somehow involve `new` and **cannot** only rely on `{}`?

Comment: It must either use `new` or else be some special implementation native to the runtime system. Is there some problem with using `new`?

Comment: No, there is no problem with `new`. I am just exploring boundaries of the newly conquered teritory.

Comment: @WiktorZychla A planned alternative is [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), which is documented in current ECMAScript 6 drafts: `var _ = {}; Object.setPrototoypeOf(_, o); return _;`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: thanks for this, it means that my intuition is correct and would just have to wait for the language to follow it :)